# Unwanted tables in our Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database

Our database contains tables such as Visitors and LandingPages for example, and I noticed earlier today that new tables have been created without any intervention from anybody on my team. The new table are named like so: Visitors03b1384cc4c745908adcc2e40bd81dac, Visitors36911dc761d04deaa418378e42e83135, LandingPages20718b591d7f4e639b66b37c443bf8e5, etc.

There is a total of about a dozen such tables that were created and I'm wondering who created them or what automated process and also if it's safe to drop these unwanted table.

Anybody has any idea what these table are for?

Comment: I'm interested in knowing the answer to this. I'm a long-time Azure user and have never seen this. Virus?

Comment: I have never seen this.

Comment: What data is in those tables?  Could it be the index tables or perhaps some additional transaction tracking tables?